# 2nd Monitor isn't recognized in Display but is usable

Tags: 15.04, ati, display, monitor

I have Ubuntu 15.04 currently installed, with the AMD display driver. AMD recognizes both monitors, and has the accurate information and resolutions on both monitors, and both monitors set to single desktop mode.

Ubuntu allows me to move the cursor to the second monitor, and I get a nice looking X cursor letting me know I can't do squat.

Steam games let me use the 2nd monitor in both eyefinity and non-eyefinity mode for the games that support it, and it works just fine.

I can change the resolution on the monitor using xrandr.

Compiz recognizes the 2nd monitor and lets me send apps to it.

However, I have no desktop on the 2nd monitor, and it doesn't show in my Display settings, and I can't "drag" a window there, or setup a workspace on that monitor...ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, switching the monitor cables on just the monitor end, with the computer turned off, and turning it back on, seems to have resolved the issue...would have been nice to find a "smart" solution, but I suppose that works.