# External Monitor has mouse but no image

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, dvi

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 side-by-side with Windows 10 on my Dell Precision 7550. I am trying to connect an older Dell 24" display (manufactured 2011) using an HDMI to DVI cable. In Windows, I have no issues when extending the two displays (laptop screen and Dell monitor). But, in Ubuntu, while it does recognize the monitor, there is an issue with actually displaying the screen. When set joining the two displays, the second monitor shows a blank screen. I am able to move the mouse between the screens, but no image. I also can not save the display settings. When set as a mirror, the monitor shows a static image that the mouse can move over. Clicking or moving windows has no effect. Unplugging and reconnecting the HDMI end of the cable to my laptop updates the image on the mirrored screen but otherwise has no effect.

Since this set up works fine when I boot into Windows, I believe this is an issue with my Ubuntu settings but as a new user, I'm not sure where to start. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714865/2nd-monitor-isnt-recognized-in-display-but-is-usable) seems to have a similar issue but doesn't offer a great solution. I ran sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196922/external-display-detected-but-stays-blank) but that also didn't solve the problem. Since its not a missing driver, what other troubleshooting options do I have?

Comment: You may also try to run a wayland session as suggested by Daniel van Vugt at launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. For me at least connecting via DisplayPort directly does wake up the screen although I have to reenable it every time after standby. Beside that the display will show a picture while booting now which has not been the case with HDMI.

I filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1915382) at launchpad against this issue.